# Android Multiple drawCircle super slow and lags in app

Tags: java, android, multithreading, view, ondraw

**Hello friends,** 
*INTRO:* I developed game named 'Sizer'. In the game u have ball and you have to press the ball, when you press the ball the size of the ball get bigger until you get the size that the level asked. While the ball get bigger you have to avoid Red balls that moving on the screen. 
*PROBLEM:* So the problem is that in advanced level, when i have for example 7 Red balls the lags begin and the CPU get very high.
So first i thought that the problem came from the draw proccess on the screen.
I moving in the same thread array of (moving coordinates) 7 balls. The game is very slow and this very bad.
(I think that the slow problem came from the drawCircle action.

**So what do you think solve the problem?**


BallView.JAVA:

```
package com.sizerapp.computer.sizer;
import  android.content.Context;
import  android.graphics.Canvas;
import  android.graphics.Color;
import  android.graphics.Paint;
import  android.view.View;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BallView extends View
{
private ArrayList<Ball> balls;
private Paint ballPaint;
private String color;
public BallView(Context context,ArrayList<Ball> nballs,String ncolor)
{
    super(context);
    this.balls = nballs;
    this.ballPaint = new Paint();
    this.color = ncolor;
}
public void setColor(String color) {this.color = color;}
private Paint getBallPaint(int i)
{
    ballPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor(this.color));
    ballPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    return ballPaint;
}
public void draw(Canvas canvas)
{
    for(int i=0;i<this.balls.size();i++)
    canvas.drawCircle(balls.get(i).getX(),balls.get(i).getY(),balls.get(i).getRadius(),getBallPaint(i));
}
}
```

BallMover.JAVA:

```
package com.sizerapp.computer.sizer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Vibrator;
public class BallMover extends Thread
{
private ArrayList<Ball> balls;
private UserBall userball;
private boolean run = true;
private GameView gameView;
private Context context;
private boolean running = true;
private int runner = 1;
private int speed;
private boolean increase ;

public BallMover(ArrayList<Ball> nballs,GameView newGameView,UserBall Nuserball,Context contextn,int nspeed)
{
    this.userball = Nuserball;
    this.balls = nballs;
    this.gameView = newGameView;
    this.run = true;
    this.context = contextn;
    this.running = true;
    this.runner = 1;
    this.speed = nspeed;
    this.increase = false;

}
public void ballsKiller()
{
    for(int i=0;i<this.balls.size();i++) {
        this.balls.remove(i);
    }

}
@Override
public void run()
{
    while(running)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<this.balls.size();i++) {
            this.balls.get(i).moveBall();
            checkHit();
        }
        this.gameView.postInvalidate();
        try
        {
            sleep(speed);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            this.run = false;
        }
    }
}
protected void onDestroy() {
    this.running = false;
}
public void checkHit()
{
    if(userball.getVulnerable()==true) {
        for(int i=0;i<this.balls.size();i++){
        if (FloatMath.sqrt(
                (userball.getX() - this.balls.get(i).getX()) * (userball.getX() - this.balls.get(i).getX())
                        +
                        (userball.getY() - this.balls.get(i).getY()) * (userball.getY() - this.balls.get(i).getY())
        ) <
                (userball.getRadius() + this.balls.get(i).getRadius())) {
            userball.setLose(true);
            // userball.setRadius(10);
            if(runner==1) {
                if(this.balls.get(i).getHelper()==true) {
                    this.balls.remove(i);
                    speed *= 3;
                }
                else
                if(this.balls.get(i).getBad()==true) {
                    this.balls.remove(i);
                    speed = 1;
                }
                else
                {

                    if(userball.getRadius()<=(userball.getWidth()/12)*3) {

                        onDestroy(); //NEW
                        this.userball.setIgnore(true);
                        // userball.setH(1);
                        userball.setCanWin(false);
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this.context, Lose.class);
                        context.startActivity(myIntent);
                        ((Activity)context).overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        runner++;
                    }
            }}
        }}
    }
}
}
```

Comment: drawCircle *will* be slow... there's a good bit of math involved in rasterizing filled circles, it's not something you'd want to do every frame. I strongly recommend using bitmaps of circles instead.

Comment: How do I use bitmap (circles) on canvas? I dont really want rewrite the whole code :'(

Comment: Look at the Bitmap APIs. You create a Bitmap, load it into a Canvas (via setBitmap) and then call drawCircle. You do this during setup, not on every draw(). In your draw() code you use canvas.drawBitmap() instead of drawCircle()... it'll be much faster. You will likely need to create a number of bitmaps with your circles at various sizes, and in draw() you choose the nearest one to your actual circle size.